# Where can I get A3 poster size of Mars Exploration Rover Spirit/Opportunity?

Tags: wheeled-robot

I am looking for A3 size poster of Mars Exploration Rover Spirit/Opportunity for robotic education.

www.sunstartoys.com gives a little postcard-size of the MER along with its components on board when you buy the toy. But this is not large enough for classroom purpose.

Does anyone know where to buy A3 size poster of these MER for robotic education?

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* ikel, but I'm afraid that [shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) are a poor fit for a stack exchange site, an answer to your question is likely to go out of date very quickly and so is very unlikely to ever help any future visitors to the site. What we prefer here are *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq)*. Also take a look at out [about] page for more information on how stack exchange works.